# initWithSize gets triggered in Objective-C but not in Swift

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skscene

I have a very simple SKScene written in Swift that doesn't get triggered:

```
override init(size: CGSize) {
    super.init(size: size)
    backgroundColor = SKColor.whiteColor()
    var bg = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "myBackground")
    bg.position = CGPoint(self.size.width/2, self.size.height/2)

    self.addChild(bg)
}
```

I've tried out the same code in Objective-C and there it gets called without a problem, so I am wondering if they've changed something with initWithSize in Swift and if I am missing something crucial.

Note: The SKScene does get triggered, only this function doesn't.

Thank you!

Comment: You need to perform super.init at the end of the intializer, perhaps that's the problem

Comment: @Eugene But if I do that, Xcode logically tells me that it can't set something before super.init initializes it.

Comment: What error are you getting? I've tried your code and get the error that you haven't provided x: and y: parameters for CGPoint initializer, so I've added them and code works properly. Have you tried settings breakpoints or prints to see if the code actually doesn't get triggered?

Comment: @Eugene "Use of method ... in base object before super.init initializes it"

But even if I remove all the code and just use super.init, the method doesn't get called ...

Comment: @Eugene Any particular reason why the `super.init` needs to be at the end?

Comment: My guess is that another initialiser is being used. I don't know much about SpriteKit, but if I create a SpriteKit-based project in Xcode 6 with Swift as the language, it looks like it warms up the GameScene from the GameScene.sks file (in GameSceneController), which calls the init(coder) method, not the init(size) method. When you get it to work in Objective C are you creating the scene object yourself? It it coming from a .sks file? (Would you be better off using `didMoveToView` rather than the initialiser?)

Comment: @MattGibson Read this https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/iOS/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html part "Designated and Convenience Initializers in Action". Basically, you need to first initialize your subclass variables and only then proceed with initializing superclass properties. Which wasn't the case in Julia's case because she had no custom properties in her superclass, thus there was really no need to move the super.init at the bottom. Regarding this problem, I agree that another initializer is probably used.

Answer (score 0):

```
In **GameViewcontroller** viewDidLoad(), Make sure your calling like this
   let skView = self.view as SKView

   let scene = **GameScene.init(size:skView.bounds.size)**
   skView.showsFPS = true
   skView.showsNodeCount = true

   /* Sprite Kit applies additional optimizations to improve rendering performance */
   skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

   /* Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window */
   scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill

   skView.presentScene(scene)


**GameScene.swift**

**init(size: CGSize)** is parameterized constructor. So you have to call it manually.

override init(size: CGSize) {
 super.init(size: size)
 backgroundColor = SKColor.whiteColor()
 var bg = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "myBackground")
 bg.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width/2, y: self.size.height/2)

 self.addChild(bg)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
 super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}
```